# How to make Paramiko run non-standard commands like iPerf

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, iperf

I want to send a command between two laptops using ssh and using Paramiko to do it. Commands such as `ls` and `echo` are working as expected, but when using non-standard commands like iPerf I get the following error:

```
['bash: iperf: command not found\n']
```

The command works fine if I open an ssh connection through my manual terminal.

Here is the code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=HOST, username=USER, password=PWD)
stdin, stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("iperf -s")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have a shell profile like `~/.bashrc` which sets your `PATH` environment variable to include nonstandard executable search paths.

To fix it, simply find out where `iperf` is located by logging in manually and running `which iperf`.  Once you have that full path, use it in your `exec_command()`.

For example, your new code might look like this:

```
ssh.exec_command("/opt/local/bin/iperf -s")
```